# local package npm error

Tags: node.js, path, npm, dependencies

I added this dependency to my package.json :

```
"user": "file:./server/models/user"
```

Inside my user file I've got `module.exports = function() {...}`

```
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /home/WebstormProjects/project/server/models/user
npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-30-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.1.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.4
npm ERR! path /home/WebstormProjects/project/server/models/user
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/WebstormProjects/project/server/models/user'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/WebstormProjects/project/npm-debug.log
```

I did follow the doc : https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths

Comment: the error is pretty clear: npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/WebstormProjects/project/server/models/user'

Comment: @Daniel But the file IS there.

Answer (score 0):

The error messages aren't very helpful, but it has to be (emphasis mine):

> a path to a local *directory* that contains a *package*

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths

You appear to be pointing it to a file. You probably need something like:

```js
"user": "file:./server/models"
```

A package also requires a `package.json`, so in that case you'd need to have `server/models/package.json`.